# Use value of variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, charts, plc, siemens, s7-1200

I'm trying to do a WEB based power management system and I'm using PLC Siemens S7-1200. I want to use some tags from PLC in javascript to build a chart. When I use:

```
var chartData = [{
    country: "USA",
    visits: 230
}, ];
```

In chart code this works fine.

Now I want to use instead of the fixed numeric value "230" a variable value with  the label "Voltage" as tag in the PLC. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value in the variable `voltage`, just use that variable in the object:

```
var chartData = [{
    country: "USA",
    visits: voltage
} ];
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/TvLHd/)

Comment: There was an extra comma before the close bracket, I've removed it.